# Keeping templates on server - Angular 2+ SPA with ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular2

We are planning to build a SPA in Angular 2+, which will use ASP.NET as a back-end. Since Angular doesn't really have a good integration to ASP.NET, we decided to create the SPA as a standalone application, which will be communicating with the WebAPI.

The first popped up question although is, how to keep the HTML templates on server? We could achieve this working with ExpressJS before, but could not find any information on how to do so in ASP.NET.

Could anyone suggest a good way to go?

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: "Angular doesnt have good integration with to ASP.net". How so? Web API is making an HTTP interface available for angular to call. How would this be more or less 'good' for a particular JS framework?

Comment: What I meant is to have everything in ASP.NET. The development is very annoying since you need to build project anytime you do changes.